# Google Analytics does not record visits

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am really desperate with Google Analytics. I tried SDK v1, v2, v3 with Google own sample codes. Flollowig the instructions, I put permissions in the Manifest, I create analytics.xml with correct tracking ID for v2 and v3, I place tracking in the code, set custom variable (as in the sample code) and do dispatch for v1. I  set  (programmatically, or in xml, whatever applies) dryRun and debug to true in order to maximize the feedback.

Everything seems to work, it reads my account and maybe even supplies data, but when I check my account on the Web, I get nice and clean 0-s in all columns, and I can't see any visits recorded!

I prefer to use v1, simply because it is the smallest, in the worst case v2, but version 3 is too big for my humble application. But any suggestion with any version will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting dryRun to true means that the library will pretend that it is sending data to GA server via logcat, but actually it is not. This is for debugging purpose. You need to turn dryRun off in order to actually send data.

From [here:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced)

> The SDK provides a dryRun flag that when set, prevents any data from being sent to Google Analytics. The dryRun flag should be set whenever you are testing or debugging an implementation and do not want test data to appear in your Google Analytics reports.

Comment: Thank you. It now works, but only with SDK 2. SDK 1 is apparently no longer supported.

Comment: A final comment: take GoogleAnalytics v3 and open jar file in ZIP editor. Remove all classes related to GTM (effectively you leave only google.analytics.tracking.android.* and google.android.gms.*). The reduces size from 900K to 114K!. Then, if you don't use EasyTracker, you can remove it along with Parameter Loader wich will further reduces size to 105K. Works perfectly!